# Eve: how my speed impacts ability of opponent to hit me?

Tags: eve-online

I'm flying thrasher.

How my speed impacts ability of opponent to hit me? Should I fly with afterburner or MWD turned on constantly? Will this reduce amount of hits my ship will get?

Or I better stop (and put off line) afterburner/MWD and save energy for shield booster?

Thanks.

Comment: You can find a very nice interactive example [here](http://go-dl.eve-files.com/media/0910/eve-tracking101.swf). It only covers turrets, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. Your speed only directly affects the amount of damage you receive from missiles. For turret weapons speed only indirectly effects how easy is to hit you.

It's actually your angular velocity relative to the attacker that affects turrets. If the turrets can't turn fast enough to track you then they'll miss. Whether or not they can track you depends on how far you are from the enemy, what direction you're going and the speed of your ship. If you're far away from the ship then you're an easy target (assuming you're still in range), since the turret doesn't have to move as fast. If you're heading straight towards or straight away from the enemy then the turret can easily track you, it doesn't have to move. If you're orbiting close and fast to the enemy then you're hard to track and so hard to hit.

Whether you're better off running a afterburner, a micro warp drive or a shield booster depends on the situation. Generally MWDs are too energy hungry to run for very long, they also have penalties that make your ship easier to hit, so with most fits they're not run all the time. Afterburners are less of a drain on your capacitors so they're easier to fit on a ship that can keep them running all the time. If you can do that and orbit enemies fast and close then you might not even need the shield booster and rely on passive shield regen. Or maybe it would be better to pulse your afterburner and shield booster as necessary to gain speed or repair your shields. Or maybe your ship is just too slow and big or the or enemies turrets are too fast so you're only option is to run the shield booster.

Whatever you do make sure you haven't equipped your ship with redundant modules, or ones you're not going to use. If you're not going to use a MWD or afterburner except occasionally don't equip one. Choose one tanking strategy. For PvE combat that means one of active shield tanking, passive shield tanking or active armour tanking. You can add speed on top of that, but one those tanking strategies is how you'll soak up the massive DPS you need to absorb during missions.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is MWD does not make you harder to hit, because the sigradius penalty cancels out with the increase in speed. Interceptors are the exception with their role bonus.